# Edit grid by column group

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I'd like to be able to edit a grid by groups of columns. For example, my grid header looks like this:

---

### DATE | TIME IN | TIME OUT |  | TIME IN | TIME OUT

I'd like to be able to edit the time columns in pairs, that is, each IN/OUT pair should be updated together. That functionality is somewhere in between cell editing and row editing. Perhaps such functionality might also require a custom selection model?

Is there a plugin, or "simple" way to do this?

Comment: You could use a cell editor, and write some code that updates the appropriate column when its paired column has been edited.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The problem with that is that the user might not update the other column. It can't be predicted. I think the ideal solution is to base it on the row editor, and use update/cancel buttons with the "group" of columns selected and in edit mode. I'm not sure if that also requires making a custom selection model for a subset of columns in a row.